# Angular material popup is not working?

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular5

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild , Inject} from '@angular/core';
import { Login }    from './login';
import {MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource, MatDialog,MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})


export class LoginComponent {

  animal: string;
  name: string;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  openDialog(): void {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: '250px',
      data: { name: this.name, animal: this.animal }
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
      this.animal = result;
    });
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog.html',
})
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

Above i have added my code i am getting below error when i run application any one help me out move forward

```
ERROR Error: No component factory found for DialogOverviewExampleDialog. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
    at noComponentFactoryError (core.js:3901)
       LoginComponent.html:101 ERROR CONTEXT
```

how to resolve this issue ...
i followed this

https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forget to add it in your `NgModule` definition inside app.module.ts.

So add it there. Below is the sample code. See, I imported `MatDialogModule`.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...
    MatDialogModule 
  ],

  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ExampleDialogComponent //DialogOverviewExampleDialog
  ],

  entryComponents: [
    ExampleDialogComponent
  ],

  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule() {}
```

**Explanation:**

For any component loaded into a dialog, you must include your component class in the list of entryComponents in your NgModule definition so that the Angular compiler knows to create the ComponentFactory for it.

Comment: 94% asset optimizationwebpack: wait until bundle finished: /login ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(113,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ExampleDialogComponent'.  getting error

Comment: This is a sample code for your example. You don't have to copy paste whole code. You need to declare your components there. I mean you are getting the error for DialogOverviewExampleDialog so declare it there in the declaration section inside app.module.ts. Remember first you have to require/import it.

Answer (score 3):

In your `app.module` add the `entryComponents` property

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ LoginComponent , DialogOverviewExampleDialog],
  entryComponents: [ DialogOverviewExampleDialog],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
```